# VSCode Git tracking colors?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

What do the various colors for VSCode files mean?

[They look like this.](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_18#_git-status-in-file-explorer)
[image]

I haven't changed the default colors, and I can't seem to find anywhere that lists what they mean.

Answer (score 6):

1. `Red` is a change that has not yet been added.
2. `Yellow` is a file that is already being tracked but has been modified since last commit.
3. `Green` is a change that you have already added to be committed.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that a go-lang linter also uses this scheme which confuses me. It makes it look like I have uncommited changes when in fact it's just some lint alert. uugh

Answer (score 3):

The ***Red Arrow*** near the no. of the line is meant that a line from the code that has been committed has been deleted.

***Yellow File*** means that the file has been modified after the last commit.

***Green File*** means that it is a newly created file.